# Не получается поместить на фоновое изображение текст и картинку

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ui

backgroun.dart:

```dart
    // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Background extends StatelessWidget {
      final Widget child;
      const Background({
        Key? key,
        required this.child,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: null,
        );
      }
    }
```

body.dart

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app1/Screens/Welcome/components/background.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
    
    class Body extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        // This size provide us total height and width of our screen
        return Background(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Добро пожаловать!\n        FREEBIE SIR",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/welcome.svg"),
                ]),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
    name: flutter_app1
    description: A new Flutter project.
    
    # The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
    # pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
    
    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
    
    # Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
    # To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
    # consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
    # dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
    # the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
    # versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1
      
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    
      # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
      # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
      # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
      # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
      # rules and activating additional ones.
      flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
    
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
    
    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
    
      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true
    
      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      assets:
        - assets/images/
        - assets/icons/
    
      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
    
      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
    
      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

welcome_screen.dart

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app1/Screens/Welcome/components/body.dart';
    
    class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Body(),
        );
      }
    }
```

main.dart

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app1/Screens/Welcome/welcome_screen.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app1/constants.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Auth',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          home: WelcomeScreen(),
        );
      }
    }
```

ошибка!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:flutter_svg
 - package:xml
 - package:path_drawing
 - package:petitparser
 - package:convert
 - package:path_parsing

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null.
#0      ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:472:9)
#1      JavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:152:33)
#2      FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:650:47)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:558:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1135:11)
<asynchronous suspension>

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

[image: дизайн]

отображается только фон, при попытке вывести текст ошибок нет. Но текста не видно. Ошибка при попытке загрузить изображение svg. изображение в формате png отображается в виде красного квадрата перечеркнутого внутри.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) и выложите пимер на [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true).

Comment: Картинка вообще отображаетя, вы её в `pubspeck.yaml` в секции `assets` прописали?

Comment: @nazarpunk в pubspeck.yaml указал, прикрепил в описании проблемы еще один скрин с ошибкой в debug console

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке вставляйте текстом.

Comment: @Glowinner почему не `2.15.1` используете, что оно на `null-safety` ругается?

Comment: @nazarpunk прикрепил полный pubspeck.yaml, 2.15.1 используется

Comment: Обновите плагин то `flutter_svg: ^1.0.3`, что `flutter pub outdated` говорит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было изменить **environment: sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"** и **cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2** на указанные значения.

```
name: flutter_app1
    description: A new Flutter project.
    
    # The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
    # pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
    
    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
    
    # Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
    # To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
    # consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
    # dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
    # the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
    # versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
      flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1
      
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    
      # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
      # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
      # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
      # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
      # rules and activating additional ones.
      flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
    
    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
    
    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
    
      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true
    
      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      assets:
        - assets/images/
        - assets/icons/
    
      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
    
      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
    
      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали `child: null` и удивляетесь что ничего не выводится:

```dart
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const Background({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: child, // <<<< !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: исправил, но debug console выдает ошибку

Comment: Тогда выкладывайте больше кода и `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: отправил весь код

Comment: Измените версию в `pubspec.yaml` с `flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1` на `flutter_svg: ^1.0.3` и не забудьте выполнить `flutter pub get`